# Ruby regex works with ruby command but not shebang

Tags: ruby, regex, shebang

I have the following 2 regular expressions in a ruby file. They run fine when i use the `ruby` command but if i try to run via `./apachereport.rb` it generates an error.

regex:

```
urls = parse(@file, /(?<=GET )\S+/)
codes = parse(@file, /(?<=HTTP\/[0-9]\.[0-9]" )\S+/)
```

error:

```
./apachereport.rb:34: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=GET )\S+/
./apachereport.rb:47: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=HTTP\/[0-9]\.[0-9]" )\S+/
```

The shebang I'm using is as follows, which seems to work fine with other ruby files:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Try `which ruby` -- When you run `ruby` is it the *same* ruby command as `apachereport.rb` is using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely explanation for this is that you have multiple versions of ruby installed. The version installed in `/usr/bin` (which is the one you're using in your shebang line) is 1.8.X, which did not support `?<=` (look-behind) in regexen. The one you execute when you type `ruby apachereport` is probably ruby 1.9, which does support `?<=`.

To verify that this is the case type in `which ruby` and notice that it prints something other than `/usr/bin/ruby` and/or compare the results of `/usr/bin/ruby --version` to `ruby --version`.